# How to delete indexed document between date ranges in SOLR Dashboard

Tags: solr, sitecore-client

I would like to delete the indexes between `date range` instead of deleting all the documents in SOLR Dashboard.
I have tried with rel_date like
`<delete><query>rel_date:[2022-01-01T00:00:00Z TO 2022-07-29T00:00:00Z]</query></delete>` but it is not working. Is it possible to delete the index between the date range?

Appreciated if anyone can help with this. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your goal you can use the following:

**POST**: `https:{SOLRENDPOINT}/solr/{corename}/update/json?commit=true`

**Headers**:
`Authorization: Bearer {token}`

In the request body, you would use the Solr delete command to specify the query for removing documents from the index. In this case, you can use a range query to specify the date range for deleting the documents.

**Body**

```
{
    "delete": {
        "query": {query for remove}  e.g. "rel_date:[2022-01-01T00:00:00Z TO 2022-07-29T00:00:00Z]"
    }
}
```

This query will remove all documents from the index that have a rel_date field within the specified date range.

Note that after sending the delete request, you will need to perform a commit operation to ensure that the index is updated. This can be done by adding the `commit=true` parameter to the request URL or by sending a separate commit request to Solr.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using a Solr query like below.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/my_core_name/update?commit=true&stream.body=<delete><query>date:[2000-01-01T00:00:00Z TO 2018-07-29T00:00:00Z]</query></delete>
```

Try this and this will work.

Use this thread for more details.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23228727/deleting-solr-documents-from-solr-admin

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I try it and it works for me. Try it with replace `__smallupdateddate_tdt` field with your field and `date value` according to your need and leave the `T` part as it is.

Also, just double check the field name is `rel_date` in Solr data.

```
<delete><query>rel_date:[2022-01-01T00:00:01Z TO 2022-07-29T23:59:59Z]</query></delete>
```

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Sumit, Thanks for the input. I have tried and i am getting the below error
Remote error message: undefined field: "__smallupdateddate_tdt".
I want to try this in xdb indexes

Comment: I mean you need to replace that field with your field. I used `__smallupdateddate_tdt` just as an example.

Comment: I've updated the query with your field. Can you try this `<delete><query>rel_date:[2022-01-01T00:00:01Z TO 2022-07-29T23:59:59Z]</query></delete>
`

Comment: @KanniyappanKrishnan - Is that resolved your issue?

Comment: Query is working but i don't see the records has deleted between the dates.

Comment: If the query is working the record should be deleted if there is no error. You can try out to delete 1 record with a specific date to see if it gets deleted.